# Comparing graph according to node values and not attributes in networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I have two `DiGraph` objects that I want to compare. I have taken a look at `is_isomorphic` but it does not fit my needs since it only allows access to node attributes and not the nodes themselves, and I want to compare the nodes themselves (using their `__eq__` methods) and return `True` if all nodes and edges are equal (I know that there is no efficient algorithms for this problem, but I don't mind efficiency for my problem).

To clarify here is a code sample, I am looking for a function similar to are_graphs_equal:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True

x = MyClass()
y = MyClass()
g1 = DiGraph()
g2 = DiGraph()
g1.add_node(x, fill='red')
g2.add_node(y, fill='blue')
are_graphs_equal(g1, g2) # should return True

g1 = DiGraph()
g2 = DiGraph()
g1.add_path(y, x)
g2.add_path(x, y)
are_graphs_equal(g1, g2) # should return False since edges are different.
```

For the sake of the question assume `MyClass` is hashable.

Thank you!

Comment: Some issues - 1) `is_isomorphic` does not "only compare node attributes" (though I don't think `is_isomorphic` will do what you want to do). 
  2) your class will need to be hashable (since networkx stores the graph as a dict).   3) It's not clear to me why the second should return `False`.

Comment: @Joel thank you for your reply! 1) I meant it only allows comparing using attributes, sorry I was unclear. 2) let's assume it's hashable, I was aiming to give as simple case as possible. 3) The second should return false since the nodes are the same but the edges are not.